# Is There Room for a 240v Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

Thanks for all the input on my previous query.  I have added a photo of the breaker box diagram showing the 5/10 hot bar blades.
Questions:
1. can the tandem and single Murray breakers be rearranged so as to fit a double pull 30 amp breaker for powering my 240v EV charger?

2. What is the significance of the connection symbols on the wiring diagram that I noted in RED?
   [image: Breaker Box]

[image: Box Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is move the second from bottom right breaker to the top left and then replace the remaining breakers on the two bottom right stabs with a quadruplex breaker with an independent trip outer pair (15/15) and common trip center pair (30).  Then you can connect the EV charger circuit to the center pair.

Otherwise, you are a half-space short of room for a 240V breaker.  The only way to make enough space in the existing panel if the second-from-bottom-right breaker can't be moved would be to use a deadfront or receptacle GFCI to provide GFCI protection to the circuit that is currently GFCI protected by the GFCI breaker in your panel, and then replace that GFCI breaker with a regular half-width breaker and rearrange the rest of the panel accordingly.

At that point, you might as well just throw a bigger panel at the problem -- 42 space panels are cheap, and if you're willing to throw some more serious cash at the problem, commercial panelboards like the Square-D NQOD line can pack up to 84 full-width slots into a single enclosure.

As to the bar? It indeed means that a two-pole or quadruplex double-stuff breaker can be put there -- it represents the common-trip function in such breakers.  Normally, this is done by an internal linkage, not a handle tie, though.

Comment: My panel is on the outside of a manufactured home.  It is only 15" x 12" in size.  I do not wish to perform any carpentry if possible..

Comment: Couldn't a double 240v breaker be placed directly opposite the input service breakers?

Comment: Shouldn't the 50 amp breakers sit directly above the input service breakers?

Comment: @JohnDyson -- is your panel surface or flush mount?

Comment: There's no need for the 50A breaker to be in any *particular* spot in the panel BTW.

Comment: The panel is flush with the outside wall of the house.  I am pretty sure the 50A circuits feeds the AC.  Can I guess that this is not a 240v circuit since it does not align properly with the L1 and L2 hot bar blades according to the diagram?  I will find out next week when I disconnect all these breakers and see just what is connected to what.

Comment: @JohnDyson -- the AC is a 240V circuit, and the breaker it's on is quadruplex, so the bottom two "breakers" are one leg and the top two "breakers" are the other leg

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-40-Amp-Double-Pole-and-2-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Type-QT-Triplex-Circuit-Breaker-Q21540CT/206632151

Comment: @JohnDyson -- you need a Q21530CT not a Q21540CT

Answer (score 0):

the bar connecting the breakers in the diagram means that the breakers are double pole, aka if one side trips then the other side trips along with it. This is required when you are driving a 240 load with it.

You can see an example of that with the 50A breaker on the left side. The white part connects the switch tabs so they always turn on and off together.